# Java's Float.floatToIntBits implementation code in C\C++

Tags: c++, c

I want the source code for java's Float.floatToIntBits() implementation code in C\C++.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be the [best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328342/) solution:

```
#include <cstring>

unsigned float_to_bits(float x)
{
    unsigned y;
    memcpy(&y, &x, 4);
    return y;
}
```

Of course this depends on float and unsigned consuming 4 bytes.

Comment: I would use `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned`. Otherwise this is a good answer.

Comment: I _think_ that this is implementing floatToRawIntBits rather than floatToIntBits

Answer (score 1):

[Google Codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ih5hvYJNSIA/src/share/classes/java/lang/Float.java&q=floatToIntBits&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) says

```
public static int floatToIntBits(float value) {
        int result = floatToRawIntBits(value);
        // Check for NaN based on values of bit fields, maximum
        // exponent and nonzero significand.
        if ( ((result & FloatConsts.EXP_BIT_MASK) ==
              FloatConsts.EXP_BIT_MASK) &&
             (result & FloatConsts.SIGNIF_BIT_MASK) != 0)
            result = 0x7fc00000;
        return result;
    }
```

Follow the link for the constants.