# convert 64-bit binary string representation of a double number back to double number in c++

Tags: c++

I have a IEEE754 Double precision 64-bit binary string representation of a double number.
example : double value = 0.999;
Its binary representation is "0011111111101111111101111100111011011001000101101000011100101011"

I want to convert this string back to a double number in c++.
I dont want to use any external libraries or .dll's as my program would operate in any platform.

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Fractions_in_binary Once you understand the theory crafting an algorithm should be simple.

Comment: I guess one question is whether the C standard guarantees that any specific size of `int` matches the size of `double`.  (I'm not a "standard lawyer" and don't know if this is the case or not.)  If not, then the job is significantly tougher.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C string solution:

```
#include <cstring>   // needed for all three solutions because of memcpy

double bitstring_to_double(const char* p)
{
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    for (; *p; ++p)
    {
        x = (x << 1) + (*p - '0');
    }
    double d;
    memcpy(&d, &x, 8);
    return d;
}
```

`std::string` solution:

```
#include <string>

double bitstring_to_double(const std::string& s)
{
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    for (std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
    {
        x = (x << 1) + (*it - '0');
    }
    double d;
    memcpy(&d, &x, 8);
    return d;
}
```

generic solution:

```
template<typename InputIterator>
double bitstring_to_double(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end)
{
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        x = (x << 1) + (*begin - '0');
    }
    double d;
    memcpy(&d, &x, 8);
    return d;
}
```

example calls:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char * p = "0011111111101111111101111100111011011001000101101000011100101011";
    std::cout << bitstring_to_double(p) << '\n';

    std::string s(p);
    std::cout << bitstring_to_double(s) << '\n';

    std::cout << bitstring_to_double(s.begin(), s.end()) << '\n';
    std::cout << bitstring_to_double(p + 0, p + 64) << '\n';
}
```

Note: I assume `unsigned long long` has 64 bits. A cleaner solution would be to include `<cstdint>` and use `uint64_t` instead, assuming your compiler is up to date and provides that C++11 header.

Comment: Why not `return *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&x);` instead of memcpy()? It seems like one of the few cases where reinterpret_cast actually makes sense.

Comment: @Adam: Because `memcpy` doesn't invoke UB. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328342/).

Comment: A strict C++ compiler will generate warnings, because you can't "just" copy bytes into an integral type like double. Of course it will still work, but if you want to be very standard compliant, I'd recommend using a union comprised of a byte array or integer type and a dummy variable of the target type. Then you shift the bits into the byte array like in the example and return the dummy variable. Ex.: `union { uint64_t src; double dst; } c; while (*s) { c.src = (c.src << 1) + (*s++ - '0'); } return c.dst;`

Comment: @onitake: Writing to one union member and then reading from another invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Thanks for the hint, I didn't know that. So, in general there is no "good" way to work around strict aliasing. Understandable, as it's not meant to be, but is there any other way for interpreting integer types as floating point?

Comment: @onitake: That's exactly what I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328342/).

Comment: `memcpy` between different types is no more "undefined behavior" than aliasing.

Comment: @FredOverflow Thank you very much. Your code works just awesome. Could you tell me if i have a string s = "0011111111101111111101111100111011011001000101101000011100101011" directly. should i have to use s.c_str() to get the const char* and pass it to the function or is there any way to operate on the string  directly. pardon me if this question is really dumb.. thanks

Comment: Calling `c_str()` would work just fine, but I added a `std::string` solution anyway, just in case. And a generic solution, this is C++ we're talking about, after all ;)

Answer (score 1):

A starting point would be to iterate through the individual characters in the string and set individual bits of an existing `double`.

Comment: can you set individual bits on a double?

Comment: Not directly, you can choose and integral type of the same size, change bits on that, and cast.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really a character string of binary bits?  If so, first convert to a 64-bit int.  Then either use a library routine (probably there is one somewhere), or more simply, use a `double` aliased over the 64-bit int to convert to `double`.

(If it's already a 64-bit int then skip the first step.)

Comment: the string is string s = "0011111111101111111101111100111011011001000101101000011100101011" ;

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring byte-ordering issues, but I suppose this should be a viable option:

The below has an outcome of .999 on i386 with gcc. See it live: **https://ideone.com/i4ygJ**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("0011111111101111111101111100111011011001000101101000011100101011");

    std::bitset<32> hi, lo;
    if (iss >> hi >> lo)
    {
        struct { uint32_t lo, hi; } words = { lo.to_ulong(), hi.to_ulong() };
        double converted = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&words);

        std::cout << hi << std::endl;
        std::cout << lo << std::endl;
        std::cout << converted << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm.. portability issues. Does anyone know whether to_ulong has guaranteed wordsize...?

Comment: I'm getting an output like the below with nan.... 00111111111011111111011111001110
11011001000101101000011100101011
0.999
nan

Comment: @Jero: hmmm, platform? I suspect you used 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

> my program would operate in any platform

Included I assume those whose double format isn't IEEE.  Something like this should work:

```
#include <math.h>

...

int const dbl_exponent_bits = 11;
int const dbl_exponent_offset = 1023;
int const dbl_significand_bits = 52;

bool negative = (*num++ == '1');
int exponent = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dbl_exponent_bits; ++i, ++num) {
    exponent = 2*exponent + (*num == '1' ? 1 : 0);
}
double significand = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < dbl_significand_bits; ++i, ++num) {
    significand = 2*significand + (*num == '1' ? 1 : 0);
}
assert(*num == '\0');
double result = ldexp(significand, exponent-(dbl_exponent_offset+dbl_significand_bits));
if (negative)
    result = -result;
```

Comment: hello, in your code what is the data type for negative, exponent, significand, result....I'm getting lot of errors while compiling...